# Mule 3 datamapper (list-of-maps to list-of-pojos) retuns empty result

Tags: datamapper, mule, pojo

I have a problem using Mule 3.3 datamapper, converting a list of maps into a list of POJOs. The source data was created by reading from a database (JDBC outbound endpoint with a SQL query), and my logger shows 2 entries before the datamapper. 
The console log shows 2 records being processed by the datamapper, including 2 POJOs being created by the POJO writer. However, immediately after the datamapper I have a logger which shows the collection size to be zero.

I have tried converting to xml and csv formats, instead of pojos, and both of these work fine.

Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong?

This is the config snippet...

```
<jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint connector-ref="jdbcConnector" queryKey="selectActuals" exchange-pattern="request-response" queryTimeout="-1" doc:name="Get actuals from DB"></jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint>
<logger level="INFO" doc:name="logger 1" message="logger 1 - list size:  #[message.payload.size()]  "/>
<data-mapper:transform config-ref="map_list_to_pojo_list" doc:name="DataMapper"/>
<logger level="INFO" doc:name="logger 2" message="logger 2 - list size:  #[message.payload.size()]  "/>
```

Comment: It's hard to help you without being able to reproduce the issue. To make it easy to reproduce I was wondering if you could try to reproduce the issue by replacing the JDBC endpoint with an expression component that creates a map. If yes, share it and also share the data mapper config + POJO (or mocks that reproduce the issue).

Comment: And also the DataMapper is an EE feature: best is to contact MuleSoft for EE-related issues as it's hard for the community to help with non-open source features.